# Finding Cumulative returns for a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, quantitative-finance

**INPUT** returns:

```
                  TSYA         AYE        YYIT
2006-08-17         nan         nan         nan
2006-08-18  1.59904743  1.66397210  1.67345829
2006-08-19 -0.37065629 -0.36541822 -0.36015840
2006-08-20 -0.41055669  0.60004777  0.00536958
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT** for cumulative_returns:

```
2006-08-17           nan
2006-08-18    5.93647782
2006-08-19   -0.57128454
2006-08-20   -0.68260542
dtype: float64
```

---

My attempt:

```
def calculate_cumulative_returns(returns):

"""
Calculate cumulative returns.

Parameters
----------
returns : DataFrame
    Returns for each ticker and date

Returns
-------
cumulative_returns : Pandas Series
    Cumulative returns for each date
"""    
res=(1 + returns).cumprod()
return pd.Series(res,index=returns.index)
```

**Error message:**

```
Output: ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 3 to array axis with dimension 4
```

---

When I run my code I get the above value error in output.

I am using python and pandas for coding. Please help me with this error. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Project question of a course... against their code of honor

Answer (score 0):

I'm am not sure about the mathematic behind your numbers, but here is what you can do to add a column that represents the product of your rows.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

Nums = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,3,2],[5,6,7]])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=Nums, columns=('a', 'b', 'c'))

df['product'] = df.prod(axis=1)
df

    a   b   c   product
0   1   2   3   6
1   4   3   2   24
2   5   6   7   210
```

My understanding is that the function `cumprod` does a cumulative product for each row or column (depending of the selected axis). The function `prod` returns only the product of all numbers in the row or column. I'm saying this because I can see the function `cumprod` in your code.

However, if you really want a sum, then just replace the function `prod` by `sum`.

```
df['Sum'] = df.sum(axis=1)

    a   b   c   Sum
0   1   2   3   6
1   4   3   2   9
2   5   6   7   18
```